# Does windows have a generic USB driver for custom devices

Tags: windows, usb

This may be a dumb question but I feel like I haven't found a solid answer on the rest of the internet or here.

Does Windows have a generic driver for custom USB devices? I am expecting some base functionality but that it may have to be modified for each device it is intended to be used with. Or do I have to create one if I want an application I'm writing to communicate with a custom USB device?

Also, if I should be asking this somewhere else let me know, I just couldn't find a better fit.

Comment: What would such a driver do?

Comment: I think you are going to have to expand on what you are after. Default and custom are very nearly opposites.

Comment: All it needs to do is let me send data from the application to the device. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You should be able to use libusb. See http://http://libusb.info .

Comment: @user4581301 is that just feedback on the question wording or is that related to how Windows views default and custom. Please explain.

Comment: @SamiSallinen, so I do have to write my own for a custom device?

Comment: Windows itself does not provide a generic driver. But you dont need to write a kernel sevice driver either. With libusb you can interdace with your device in user mode code.

Comment: @SamiSallinen, thank you. If this were an answer I would consider it the accepted answer.

Comment: Feedback on question wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows itself does not have a generic driver. However, you don't need to write a kernel driver. With libusb - see http://libusb.info - you should be able to interface with your device from user mode code.